# linux cpio to copy directory structure and file names?

Tags: linux, command-line, data-transfer, cpio

I want to copy a directory structure from a remote machine to a local machine. I want the file names too but not the content of the file.

Presently I did this in the remote machine:

```
find . -type d -print | cpio -oO dirs.cpio
```

then copied the `dirs.cpio` file to local machine, and ran the command after going to directory where I want the structure replicated:

```
cpio -iI dirs.cpio
```

So this creates the directory structure I want including subdirectories, but does not copies the **file names**. I want the directory structure and file names but **not** their content.

How can I get the file names too??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier without cpio.  On the source:

```
find . -exec ls -Fd {} + > stuff
```

This makes a file listing all directories (with trailing slashes thanks to `ls -F`) and files.

On the destination:

```
./makestuff < stuff
```

Where `makestuff` is this script:

```
while read name; do
  if [ "${name:${#name}-1}" = "/" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$name"
  else
    touch "$name"
  fi
done
```